# How can I set height automatically when using swiper in flutter?

Tags: flutter, height

I am using the swiper with the height of the container fixed as follows, but I want to make the height value automatically adjust according to the contents inside the swiper.

```
Container(
    height: 220,
    child: Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container() //content
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: What is Swiper? Is this your custom widget?

Comment: just use tab controller and tabBarView if you want those kind of things